# Excel VBA & nested ifs

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, vba

I'm trying to delete a row in Excel 2007 via VBA if it meets two requirements: A a termination date greater than one provided (variable datesToRemoveTerminatedMembersFrom) and also if there is a "D" in column R.

The code I'm using does not give me an error, but does not delete the row either:

```
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Range("R" & i).Value = "D" Then
        If Range("D" & i).Value > datesToRemoveTerminatedMembersFrom Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

They both work by themselves, but not if I nest them.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: it works for me..Have you defined `lastRow` ?

Comment: Hi Sam092 lastRow was defined earlier in the script

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If UCase(Range("R" & i).Value) = "D" Then
        If CDate(Range("D" & i).Value) > CDate(datesToRemoveTerminatedMembersFrom) Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I tried this but it deleted everything with a D value in column R.

Comment: @Chris Add breakpoint at `If CDate(Range("D" & i).Value) > CDate(datesToRemoveTerminatedMembersFrom) Then` .This will show how the condition is working. Make sure the date are in same format.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't need this anymore.  The person I was setting up the spreadsheet application for requested that I delete each record where the termination date was greater than the filedate.

What she **actually meant** was replace the termination date with "", not delete the row, doh.

Thanks for your help, the code I used in the end was:

```
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1

        If CDate(Range("D" & i).Value) > CDate(datesToRemoveTerminatedMembersFrom) Then
            Range("D" & i) = ""
        End If

Next i
```